# Is there a version of Chrome OS I can reliably install onto old Dells?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

We currently use Ubuntu to breathe new life into old machines (3 years old), but we use Google Apps for everything so it makes sense to have the 'full' experience of Chrome OS. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try it and feel it..but Chrome OS was proprietary OS embedded with Google Chromebook, so if you need to install Chrome OS, you can choose Chromium OS. here you can get Chromium OS http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/download/vanilla?&version=4019.0.2013_04_18_1817-r8d17ae3f&type=usb